# NavigateUrl of custom button

Tags: acumatica

I've added one button in Case page to try to redirect to external site and passing out CASEID, this is the button generated:

```
<px:PXButton runat="server" ID="CstButton1" Text="Send CASE" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl="http://mycase.com/load.htm?caseid=#####" />
```

but where/how should I modify BLC to get current CaseID and modify the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be done in a graph extension using something like the following:

```
public PXAction<MyPrimaryDac> OpenCaseButton;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "View Ext Case")]
[PXButton]
protected virtual void openCaseButton()
{
    string myCaseNbr = "123";
    throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(
        string.Format("http://mycase.com/load.htm?caseid={0}", myCaseNbr),
        PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow, 
        "");
 }
```

The graph extension code example above will add a button to the page (no need to add a button on the page). Most likely you will want to add your button within the standard page's action menu buttons. I think the Acumatica training material covers this (T100,T200,T300). View the Acumatica source to find examples using PXButtons (or other button attributes).

Comment: Thanks Brendan, I figured that out after I found PXRedirectToUrlException.  I guess I need to get more familiar with classes, exceptions and attributes of Framework.